# get SharedPreferences from a service

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sharedpreferences, preferences

I am trying to access shared preferences from a service. I have used the the following to save the value of text to a string...

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString("Ignore1_value", Example.getText().toString());
editor.commit();
```

But, how would i get the value in a service? Everything i have tried returns as nothing. Any help would be perfect and much appreciated?

I looked through some other questions as well with no solution. I have came up with this, but like i said it returns it as no text.

```
Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
    String example1string = sharedPreferences.getString("Ignore1_value","");
    Log.i("**GetSettings", example1string);
```

Comment: try `SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(youActivity.this);` when you are saving the value..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm always using `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)`. This is the same for all `Context`s in your application.

A `Service` is a `Context` itself, so this would be sufficient:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```